# Replacing multiple slashes in URL with a single slash

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I have the following htaccess rule that I would like to use in order to redirect `www.example.com//test.html` (any number of consecutive slashes) to `www.example.com/test.html`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //+
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [R=301,L]
```

It works on my local instance on MAMP, but, it will not redirect the multiple slashes unless there are more than 2 on a production environment (Amazon). So..

```
www.example.com//test.html --> www.example.com//test.html (doesn't work)
```

But

```
www.example.com///test.html --> www.example.com/test.html (works)
```

However, if there are multiple occurrences of multiple slashes, all of them are replaced by single slashes sometimes like below.

```
www.example.com//test//test.html --> www.example.com/test/test.html (works)
www.example.com//test/test.html --> www.example.com//test/test.html (doesn't work)
```

What's going on? I've read numerous posts on this, and none of them seem to work.

Comment: Have you found a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

So you rely on webserver that it will always replace multiple slashes for (.*) which is not mandatory by the specification.

What you can do is to create multiple rules for 1,2,3 occurrences of multiple slashes, like

RewriteRule (.+)//+(.+) $1/$2 [r=301,l]

And so on. Start from 3, then 2, then 1 as the order is matter in this approach.

Not ideal, but might help.

Comment: What's the `+` for? e.g. `(.+)`

Comment: .+ is 1 or more characters, () means we remember the match